# Объявление и заполнение индекса ассоциативного массива

Tags: oracle, plsql, коллекции, index, индексация

При написании программы появилась необходимость в создании ассоциативного массива с использованием индекса, в связи с этим есть несколько вопросов:

Правильно понимаю, что при объявлении индекса тип данных может быть только `varchar2`, `BINARY_INTEGER`, `PLS_INTEGER`, никаких `integer` и `number`?

Допустим, я объявил для массива индекс `index by SALE_TRANS.Player_Info%type`, затем в теле программы я заполняю массив данными:

```sql
select
     Player_Info(varchar2),
     id (number),
     trns(integer),
     email(varchar2) bulk collect into happy
from SALE_TRANS t
where t.Trns_ID = 2497170`
```

Индекс автоматически создастся по столбцу Player_Info?

Если я объявляю индекс `index by VARCHAR2(3333)`, то при заполнении массива:

```sql
select
     Player_Info(varchar2),
     id (number),
     trns(integer),
     email(varchar2) bulk collect into happy
from SALE_TRANS t
where t.Trns_ID = 2497170
```

То индекс создастся на каком столбце?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрим, что говорит об [ассоциативных коллекциях оф.источники](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-8060F01F-B53B-48D4-9239-7EA8461C2170) (выделил жирным то, что надо обязательно понять и усвоить):

> An associative array (formerly called **PL/SQL table or index-by table**) is **a set of key-value pairs**. Each key is a unique index, used to locate the associated value with the syntax `variable_name(index)`.
>
> The data type of index can be **either a string type (VARCHAR2, VARCHAR, STRING, or LONG) or PLS_INTEGER**. Indexes are stored in **sort order**, not **creation order**.

То есть, лучше представить, что ассоциативные коллекции это упорядоченный по уникальному ключу набор значений, чем индексированный набор значений.

В SQL запросах могут использоваться только ассоциативные коллекции с типом ключа - `PLS_INTEGER`. При этом, текущему ключу будет присвоено значение не какого-либо столбца, а именно порядковый номер записи в результирующем наборе (*result set*). То ест, это всегда и без исключений последовательность без пропусков - 1..N (отсюда и устаревшее название - *index by table*).

Исходя из выше изложенного, если предполагаеется использовать ассоциативные коллекции, как показанно в вопросе, то лучше сразу обратится к вложенным таблицам.

---

В заключениe, несколько воспроизводимых примеров (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bb8a30e35402211e94665c12e6be9e73)). Подготовка схемы:

```
create table t (id, memo, created) as
    select rownum, 'memo '||lpad (rownum, 4, '0'), sysdate
    from dual connect by level<=3;
/
create or replace package pack as
    type rec is record (id int, memo varchar2 (96), created date default sysdate);
    type arrbynum is table of t%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    type arrbykey is table of t%rowtype index by varchar2 (32);
end;
/
```

В SQL запросах не могут быть использованы ассоциативные коллекции с символьным типом ключа:

```
declare k pack.arrbykey;
begin
    select * bulk collect into k from t;
end;
/
```

> PLS-00657: Implementation restriction: bulk SQL with associative arrays with VARCHAR2 key is not supported.

Функционал в #1 и #2 полностью эквивалентен, #2 поясняет, что делает "под капотом" #1:

```
declare
    n pack.arrbynum;
    rc sys_refcursor;
    rec t%rowtype;
begin
    --#1
    select * bulk collect into n from t;
    --#2
    open rc for select * from t;
    loop fetch rc into rec;
        exit when rc%notfound;
        n(rc%rowcount) := rec; 
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Инициализацию ассоциативной коллекции данными из SQL запроса можно выполнить так:

```
declare 
    k pack.arrbykey;
    key char (8);
begin
    for r in (select * from t) loop
        key := 'code'||lpad (r.id, 4, '0');
        k (key) := r;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Да, верно.

2,3. Bulk Collect не работает с ассоциативными массивами, кроме индексированых pls_integer. Если pls_integer, то вам надо указывать отдельные поля:

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name 
    BULK COLLECT INTO   enums, names
    FROM   employees
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, поля я указываю при создании типа массива?
И конкретно в Вашем примере индекс будет по столбцу employee_id (т.к. у него тип pls_integer) ?

Comment: Вы создаете тип массива, а потом ниже создаете коллекцию (поле) привязанную к этому типу

Comment: Получается, что скрипт должен выглядеть следующим образом?

declare
 type list_of is table of SALE_TRANS%rowtype index by pls_integer;
 enums list_of;
 names list_of;
 id list_of;
 id_trns list_of;
begin
  SELECT employee_id, last_name ,id,id_trns
    BULK COLLECT INTO   enums, names,id,id_trns
    FROM   employees;
end;

А тогда на какой столбец создастся индекс?

Comment: Код почти правильный, если вы создаете тип на строку целиком, то достаточно так писать: ........ record list_of; ........ SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO record FROM employees; ....... А вот на какой столбец тут индекс точно не могу сказать...

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Просто мне очень важно понять как индекс инициализируется, тк данных много, индекс необходим)из-за него и выбрал использование ассоциативного массива)

Comment: Тут наверно надо уже к первичной документации Oracla обращаться) Самому интересно стало, в литературе про это не пишется...

Comment: угу)
поэтому и решил здесь спросить))